# Setting the margin of an img in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

The code below adjusts the margin of an img, so it's centered in an div with width of 600px. It works in general, but sometimes it doesn't and a second call is required.

Edit: Forgot to mention: This function is triggered by another, who is setting the source of the image to another, therefore changing the image.

Any help?

```
function adjustMargin(imageId) {
var image = document.getElementById(imageId);
image.setAttribute("style", "margin: 0 " + (300 - image.clientWidth / 2).toString() + "px");
}
```

The not-so-well working example can be seen [here](http://lukasbaumgartner.ch/test/projekte.html).

Comment: Could you provide an example of where it doesn’t work?

Comment: why on earth are you doing this? Surly there is a purly Css solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use css:

```
#imgId {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    // you are subtracting 300px and dividing by 2 
    // so assume your image is 300px wide
    width: 300px; 
}
```

The img tag is an **inline** element and as `margin: 0 auto` will only work on **block** elements you have to include `display: block` on the img css.

An alternative to center **inline** elements is:

```
#imgId {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Demo of both methods [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/SGhUV/1/)

Comment: I already tried: It's not working. The margin seems to stay the same value.

Comment: @muma Than you should show a relevant css/html for your problem. Possibly on http://jsfiddle.net so everyone can see it in action.

Comment: make sure you haven't floated your image and that it is inside a block level element

Answer (score 1):

First - correct way for setting styles is:

```
image.style.margin = "margin: 0 " + (300 - image.clientWidth / 2).toString() + "px";
```

(well, maybe there is no difference, but `.style` propery is supposed to be used for changing style of elements with JS)

Second - are you sure image is already loaded when that code is executed? If no - `image.clientWidth` might be not available yet. You may need to use `onload` event to run that code when image is loaded for sure.

Third - as stated in [Bruno's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13342821/1558311) answer, `margin:0 auto;` will automatically place your image centered inside a div, so no JS required at all.

**EDIT:**

But with 3rd approach you have a problem because image is not a block element. In order to make it work do something like this:

```
<div style="
    width: 600px;
"><img src="Bilder/re-tabouret/lukas_baumgartner_re_tabouret_1@b.jpg" alt="mainArticleImg" class="projektMainImg" id="01:00" style=""></div>
```

wrap image into div with specified width and update css like this:

```
img.projektMainImg {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 600px;
max-height: 400px;
display: block;
}
```

(see `display:block` added)
Or simply wrap image with a div with specified width and add `text-align:center` to its style (no display block and margins needed):

```
<div style="
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
"><img src="Bilder/re-tabouret/lukas_baumgartner_re_tabouret_1@b.jpg" alt="mainArticleImg" class="projektMainImg" id="01:00" style=""></div>
```

Wraper div is required in order to center image in left 600px area. Otherwise it will be centered relatively to `<div class="projektImages">`

Comment: Why the double margin? Wouldn't image.style.margin = "0 auto"; suffice?

Comment: Thanks, Bruno already mentioned it. My mistake. The changes are already implemented, but not online.

display: block;! Another forgotten thing...